# How to run Visual studio remote debugger in service mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I want to run the remote debugger of visual studio 2005 in service mode.. It is running fine in application mode, and when in service mode it starts successfully but I can't connect from the remote system.. Is their any special setting required.. Please help me out.

Comment: Hvae you checked Windows Firewall?

Comment: Yes it is turned off on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

Check which user you have it running under as a service. The remote debugger requires that all users involved have admin permissions on both machines. If you're running under something like the "local service" user it won't have the required permissions.

Start by trying to run it as the same user as you ran it in app mode. If that works you know that your problem is to do with permissions.

Also, try ticking the "allow service to interact with desktop" option. you probably won't want to leave it permanently like this, but it might allow it to report an error to you that will help you figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I have checked the permissions they are administrative on both systems, but the strange thing i have notices is that the process "msvsmon.exe" is running but when I check "netstat -ab" command there is no process named msvsmon.exe there?? what might be this problem.

Comment: Are you using the "local system/service" user? Try changing it to use a proper user rather than "local system/service", the "local system/service" accounts are specific to each machine and don't have network access.

Comment: local PC admin or domain admin?